# Getting an exception that triggered "Failed calling MyClass::jsonSerialize()" exception

Tags: php, json, error-handling

This example:

```
<?php

    class MyCustomException extends Exception {

    }

    class MyClass implements JsonSerializable {

        function jsonSerialize() 
        {
            throw new MyCustomException('For some reason, something fails here');
        }

    }

    try {
        json_encode(new MyClass);
    } catch(Exception $e) {
        print $e->getMessage() . "\n";
    }
```

Will output: `Failed calling MyClass::jsonSerialize()`. How to get `MyCustomException`, that's the actual cause of this error?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The answer is in `previous` property of the `Exception` class. To get the original exception, `try - catch` block should be altered a bit:

```
try {
    json_encode(new MyClass);
} catch (Exception $e) {
    if ($e->getPrevious()) {
        print $e->getPrevious()->getMessage() . "\n";
    } else {
        print $e->getMessage() . "\n";
    }
}
```

This exception can also be re-thrown:

```
try {
    json_encode(new MyClass);
} catch (Exception $e) {
    if ($e->getPrevious()) {
        throw $e->getPrevious();
    } else {
        throw $e;
    }
}
```